# How to create array of strings in mvc 5

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc

Client code

```
var availableTags = ["tag1", "tag2"];
```

I take tags from database, how to create variable in mvc 5? I want to write this:

```
var availableTags = @ViewBag.Tags;
```

I've tried

```
ViewBag.Tags = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new List<string>() { "Tag1", "Tag2" });
```

But this doesn't work

Comment: how you want you use `availableTags`?

Comment: `var availableTags = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Tags))';`

Comment: @AdilMammadov As source for tagit.js, ["tag1","tag2"] - I need this format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Json.Encode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

*Server side*

```
ViewBag.Tags = new List<string>() { "Tag1", "Tag2" };
```

*Client Side*

```
var availableTags = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Tags));
```